# Unstable manifold of a three dimensional dynamical system

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

What is the algorithm to find unstable manifold of a three dimensional autonomous system? Can anyone give me any reference for sample code?

Comment: What is the dimension of unstable manifold? Do you want a local unstable manifold or global? Do you want a piece of code that you can easily duplicate for your purposes or just a working code?

Comment: The dimension of the unstable manifold is one.  If there is any working code with you that could be duplicated to any three dimensional dynamical system then I would welcome. Actually, I want to study the three dimensional rate equations for lasers with optical injection. I want to generate the unstable manifold in fig. 4 of https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.063901

Comment: Oh, actually you want to compute a bit more intricate thing: Figure 4 shows homoclinic orbits :) If you are not into coding such things yourself, you may try to find help in [AUTO manual](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/sandsted/auto/auto07p.pdf) or in [XPP manual](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~bard/bardware/xpp_doc.pdf). If you want just one homoclinic trajectory, it could be done without these packages. But doing the bifurcation diagram without them is pretty tough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Even the authors of this paper have used AUTO to do all computations. I think Fig.4 shows unstable manifold which is part of a homoclinic orbit. I don't want the bifurcation diagram rather I am interested in reproducing Fig.4 only using some code. I referred following book for the algorithm but I think it will take a long time for me because I am not much involved in coding such algorithms: Practical Numerical Algorithms for Chaotic Systems by Parker and Chua- Chapter6

Comment: I'll try to write answer with explanaion soon.Regarding the chapter from Parker-Chua, they have the simplest approximation to local (un)stable manifold too: just take corresponding eigenvectors and scale them to fit in a small neighbourhood of equilbrium.The global part can be computed by any numerical integrator: just take the "tip" of this scaled eigenvector as an initial condition and it will work.However, finding the parameter value for which homoclinic orbit exists is either tedious manual labor or requires some additional coding. f you are OK with first option, you can do it right now :)

Comment: If you see the caption of Fig.4 then you will find that the parameter (K,$\omega$) values for each unstable manifold are given. One point I want to say, the unstable manifolds are not for the parameters on the homoclinic bifurcation rather they are near the homoclinic bifurcation curve. See the following statement in the paper: "For values of K and $\omega$ inside each tongue bounded by $h^n$ and below ns we find multipulse excitability. Figure 4 shows this for (K, $\omega$) inside the tongues bounded by the curves $h^1, h^2, h^3$, and $h^4^ from Fig. 3(b)."

Comment: Hence, I think they don't exactly represent homoclinic orbits. These unstable manifolds belong to a situation just after the bifurcation.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but they are tightly connected to them: in some cases the desctruction of homoclinic orbit leads to creation of limit cycle near the place where homoclinic orbit were. They refer to it as to "simple Shilnikov bifurcation". So you don't really have to find homoclinic points :)

Comment: So can you suggest, with the given three dynamical equations with parameters given in simple Shilnikov bifurcation region, how can I obtain the unstable manifold in Fig.4? If any algorithm or code then fine otherwise any tool which can do this.

Comment: Yeah, sure :) If you know coordinates of saddle-focus $\mathbf{p}$ and the unstable eigenvector $\mathcal{v}$, then $\mathbf{p} \pm \varepsilon \mathcal{v}$ is a nice approximation for exit points of $W^u$. You can take this point as an initial condition for any numerical integrator and start trajectory from it. This would be your unstable manifold :) The same method was suggested in the Chua-Parker book, I've already commented on that.

Comment: thanks! I will try to do it as you said but can you tell me the best way to find the saddle focus and the eigenvectors. Which tool can do this for three dimensional system? Like PPlane does this for 2-dimensional systems.

Comment: Hm, do you know Python? You can use routines like `fsolve` from SciPy to find equilibria, but you have to have some initial guess for this procedure to work (you might get it from plots in article). Also SciPy/NumPy have routines for finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors. And of course SciPy has Odeint for numerical solutions of differential equations.

Comment: I know Python. I will use scipy.optimize.fsolve. I have written a rk4 subroutine to find solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Just an advice: the versions of numeric integrators that were written by someone else can sometimes be much faster ;) For example, PyDSTool converts the right hand side to C/Fortran code and it's super fast.